# My footercallback function is calculated for last page only and not the current page

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

I have a problem with Footercallback function. Calculated total value is worked for last page only , not for current page.

Here is my problem . Now it only have 5 pages. and when i go page 4. But it does not show page 4 of value. It is calculated and show of page 5 value only.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7MoI.png)

And here is the real actual value of page 5 . So this means it only works for last page only.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ocV6A.png)

My code is like this.

$('#tbl-treport').dataTable({

```
    "footerCallback": function ( row, data, start, end, display ) {
        var api = this.api(),data;

        // converting to interger to find total
        var intVal = function ( i ) {
            return typeof i === 'string' ?
                i.replace(/[\$,]/g, '')*1 :
                typeof i === 'number' ?
                    i : 0;
        };

        // computing column Total of the complete result 


        var from_amount_in_sgd = api
        .column( 8, { page: "current"} )
        .data()
        .reduce( function (a, b) {
            return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
        } ,0);
```

var numFormat = $.fn.dataTable.render.number( '\,', '.', 3).display;

```
        $( api.column( 6 ).footer() ).html("Total Amounts");

        $( api.column( 8 ).footer() ).html(numFormat(from_amount_in_sgd));
```

},

```
} );

$("#tbl-treport").dataTable().fnDestroy();
```

} );

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer because of this line of code.
$("#tbl-treport").dataTable().fnDestroy();

so need to change $("#tbl-treport").dataTable().Destroy();

So it works now.